# Windows File Owner shows as ellipsis (...)

Tags: windows, windows-xp

When I list a directory on my WinXP machine, one of the files shows up with three dots (...) in the owner field. What does this mean?

Answer (score 3):

Its most likely either a deleted user or the width of the field in explorer isnt big enough to list the full username

Comment: I'd def say the field isn't big enough, you get a GUID when you delete a user and the perms aren't removed